# Popup notification that stays when linking to another page

Tags: jquery, notifications, popup

Is it possible to have a popup notification (the one that does NOT require clicking ok/cancel, simply a bar that appears at top of browser similar to this: http://needim.github.com/noty/) that **stays** in the browser when linking between html pages? I've tried to add the mentioned JQuery popup to a link to another page, but obviously the notification disappears the moment I click the link before it even fully shows up.

E.g.:

```
<!--page1.html-->

<script type="text/javascript">
function generate(type) {
  var n = noty({
    text: type,
    type: type,
    dismissQueue: false,
    layout: 'topCenter',
    theme: 'defaultTheme'
  });
}

$(document).ready(function() {

$('#link').click(function() {
    generate('Your language choice was set');       
} );

</script>


<a href="page2.html" id="link">link to another page</a>
```

Clicking the link is supposed to cause that notification bar to pop up on the top of the browser, but since it links to page2.html, before the bar loads it'll disappear as page2.html would've loaded.

Comment: You'd have to use a separate browser window for that functionality.

Comment: As a user, that sounds really annoying to me.  You might try building a page that has an absolutely-positioned div with a transparent background, and an absolutely-positioned iframe to display the URL.

Comment: @slashingweapon - Agreed.  I was also going to write an answer suggesting the iframe, but realized that also just presents user experience issues and potential head-aches...

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using statically linked pages for links, you can change the content of your page with javascript and ajax requests when the user clicks links on the page.

In general, navigating to a new page will destroy DOM content from the previous page (such as that popup).  I suppose technically you could store that information in a cookie that tries to recreate the popup on each page based on the previous state, but that seems unnecessarily complicated over the ajax option.